# How to start Tunnelblick VPN connection via Terminal

Tags: terminal, vpn

I can connect/disconnect using the Tunnelblick app. How do I connect via the command line?

`/Applications/Tunnelblick.app/Contents/Resources/openvpnstart start ???`

How do I determine the parameters to pass?

Comment: As @Mikey T.K. said, it would be easier to control it with apple script, you can see the dictionary to  see all commands. You directly run openvpn but then you might miss a option or something. I have a LaunchBar Action to control VPN with that, if you're interested.

Comment: @user14492 you mean something like this? https://github.com/hlissner/lb6-actions/tree/master/VPN.lbaction/Contents

Comment: @lucianf Yep that's the one! Can't believe you actually found it. :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A possibly better idea than messing around with openvpn directly (Tunnelblick is basically just a fancy GUI around it) would be to use an Applescript, something that can definitely be launched from the terminal (i.e. with `osascript`)

Example taken from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tunnelblick-discuss/1MDrN6__mdA):

```
tell application "Tunnelblick"
    connect "Company_VPN"
    get state of first configuration where name = "Company_VPN"
    repeat until result = "CONNECTED"
        delay 1
        get state of first configuration where name = "Company_VPN"
    end repeat
end tell
```

You'd write this into the Script Editor, save it, and then you could launch it from the terminal with `osascript`, or by double clicking on the script.

Comment: Use the AppleScript Editor to save to connect.scpt and run with `osascript connect.scpt`

Comment: Probably should have mentioned that the first time. Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use [tunblkctl](https://github.com/azhuchkov/tunblkctl). It's lightweight and gets the job done. You can quickly install it using Homebrew and then utilize it for various OpenVPN-related automation workflows on macOS.

Disclosure: I am the author.